# Update database from bootstrap modal using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am creating a page which displays some records from the database (please refer to the screen shots). Each row has an edit button which opens up a bootstrap modal for inputing comments and changing the user's status. On clicking the done button, I have to update the changes in the database preferably using AJAX. However it's not properly working. I can't seem to understand what's going wrong.
[image: Displaying records from database]
[image: Modal for adding comments and changing status of user]

This is my jsp page...

```
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>

    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%
    String loginIdEdit = "";
%>



                    **<script>
                        $(function() {
                            //twitter bootstrap script
                            $("button#save").click(function(e) {

                                $.ajax({

                                    type : "POST",
                                    url : "defaulterUpdater.jsp",
                                    data : $('form.contact').serialize(),
                                    success : function(msg) {

                                    },
                                    error : function() {
                                        alert("Failed");
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    </script>**

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFun() {
        alert("welcome");
        var demo = document.createElement('div');
        demo.innerHTML = demo.innerHTML
                + "<tr><input type='text' name='mytext'><tr>";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="RegistrationServlet">

            <%
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
                response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
                Connection con = null;

                con = DBManager.getConnection();
                Statement st = con.createStatement();

                String userName = "";
                ArrayList<AutoDefaulterVO> defaulterList = null;

                HttpSession session2 = request.getSession();
                if (session2.getAttribute("first_name") == null) {
                    out.println("Your session expired.....");
            %>



            <a href="Home.jsp">Please Login Again to continue</a>
            <%
                } else {
                    defaulterList = (ArrayList<AutoDefaulterVO>) session2
                            .getAttribute("autoDefaulterList");
                    userName = session2.getAttribute("first_name").toString();
            %>

            <form action='LogoutServlet' method=POST>
                <table align="right" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><input type="submit" name="logout"
                            value="Home" onclick="form.action='AdminHome';">
                        </td>
                        <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="logout"
                            value="Logout" onclick="form.action='LogoutServlet'">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>



            <h3 align="center">Auto Defaults</h3>
            <table border="1" style="width: 100%">
                <br>
                <br>


                <h3 align="center">
                    Welcome
                    <%=userName%></h3>

                <table border="1" style="width: 100%" class="table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Default Status</th>
                        <th>Borrower Name</th>
                        <th>Borrower Rating</th>
                        <th>Accural Status</th>
                        <th>Bank Number</th>
                        <th>Account Number</th>
                        <th>Days Past Due</th>
                        <th>Comments</th>
                    </tr>

                    <%
                        for (int i = 0; i < defaulterList.size(); i++) {
                                AutoDefaulterVO defaulter = new AutoDefaulterVO();
                                defaulter = defaulterList.get(i);
                                loginIdEdit = defaulter.getDefaulterLoginID();
                                System.out.println("Printing only auto defaulter in jsp ");
                    %>
                    <tr>
                        <%-- <td><%=defaulter.getDefaultStatus()%></td> --%>

                        <td>Auto Defaulter</td>
                        <td><%=defaulter.getBorrowerName()%></td>
                        <td><%=defaulter.getBorrowerRating()%></td>
                        <td><%=defaulter.getAccuralStatus()%></td>
                        <td><%=defaulter.getBankNumber()%></td>
                        <td><%=defaulter.getAccountNumber()%></td>
                        <td><%=defaulter.getDaysPastDue()%></td>
                        <%-- <td><%=loginIdEdit%></td> --%>
                        <td>
                            <%
                                ResultSet rs = st
                                                .executeQuery("select * from aip_comments");
                                        while (rs.next()) {
                                            System.out.println("Auto defaulter loginId printing-->"
                                                    + defaulter.getDefaulterLoginID());
                                            String loginId = rs.getString("login_id");
                                            System.out.println("databse loginId printing-->"
                                                    + rs.getString("login_id"));
                                            if (defaulter.getDefaulterLoginID().equals(
                                                    rs.getString("login_id"))) {
                            %> <%=rs.getString("comments")%> <%
    }
            }
 %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <!-- <form name="editForm" action="edit.jsp">
                            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-default" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button>

                            -->
                            <form class="contact">


                                <button href="#edit-modal" type="button" data-toggle="modal"
                                    class="btn btn-default" data-target="#<%=loginIdEdit %>">Edit</button>
                                <!-- <a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%=loginIdEdit%>" href="#">Edit</a> -->

                                <!-- <input type="submit" name="editButton" value="Edit"> -->
                                <!--<input type="hidden" id="edit" name="edit" value="<%=loginIdEdit%>" />-->
                        </td>

                        <div class="modal fade" id="<%=loginIdEdit%>" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">
                                            Edit status and add comment for
                                            <%=defaulter.getBorrowerName()%></h4>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-body">


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="sel1"><span></span>Select status:</label> <select
                                                class="form-control" id="sel1" name="sel1">
                                                <option>Validate Error</option>
                                                <option>Auto Weaver</option>
                                                <option>ReDefault</option>
                                            </select>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="defaultercomment"><span></span>Add
                                                comment:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                                name="defaultercomment" id="defaultercomment"<%-- value="<%=loginIdEdit%>" --%>>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" id="save" name="save"
                                            class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" align="centre">Done</button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                        <%
                            }
                        %>
                    </tr>

                </table>




                <%
                    }
                %>

</body>
</html>
```

ajax URL redirects to below jsp page,defaulterUpdater.jsp where I only print the values to see if they're correctly retrieved.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% String selection = request.getParameter("sel1");
String comment = request.getParameter("defaultercomment");

System.out.println("selection-"+selection+"comment--"+comment);
%> 


</body>
</html>
```

The values are accepted only for the first row..For rest of the rows null values are being printed. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is your click event triggred on btnSave click of the modal?

Comment: Yes it is triggered...The correct values are passed via ajax only for the first row.. For other rows blank values are passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the code working. Basically needed an unique identifier for "done" button as is rule of javascript. Hence it was not working for all rows. 
I gave unique id's to the form 
and by submitting called the onclick method..
onClick="callAjax(this.form)"

So now it's working. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Great, seems you resolved it but don't you think you  reapeated your form for each edit button , if there are 100 rows then there will be 100 forms which may lead slow rendering performance wise.

Comment: Yes that's true.. But I urgently needed a solution to this. Will have to think of something better.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the modal wrong inside the table. By table syntax it is wrong. You must put this modal out from the table and call ajax inside the shown.bs.modal event of bootstrap.

As you need to repeat buttons. Keep a hardwired id of the button which will open the modal, also keep an data-attribute-id to uniquely identify the button clicked which will help you to get details about which button clicked in the list(as buttons are repeating for each row, your data-attribute-id will be loginid of the row).

Then write jquery with event shown.bs.modal, like

```
$("#modalId").on("shown.bs.modal", function(e){
var btnClicked= $(e).relatedTarget();
var btnClickedId= btnClicked.data("attribute-id"); // id of clicked button

// here more code see attached link below for more

}
```

I have posted a similer answer previously in asp.net mvc but you will have idea as situation is similer to you.
Please visit my answer on question [dynamically created bootstrap3 modals do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507649/dynamically-created-bootstrap3-modals-do-not-work)

Hope it will help to get idea to resolve this.

**@Update Section** Removed your some code for clean view

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#editModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);//Button which is clicked
            var clickedButtonId= button.data('loginidedit');//Get loginidedit of the button or get other variable same
          $("#loginid").val(clickedButtonId);//Put here id of the btn clicked which has attribute for loginidedit
    //you can get here other required filed or make ajax call to get other values formt he database for                  this loginidedit.

        })
    });
</script>



<body>
    <div class="container">

//Table here
          <table border="1" style="width: 100%" class="table table-hover"> 
                    <%
                        for (int i = 0; i < defaulterList.size(); i++) {
                                AutoDefaulterVO defaulter = new AutoDefaulterVO();
                                defaulter = defaulterList.get(i);
                                loginIdEdit = defaulter.getDefaulterLoginID();
                                System.out.println("Printing only auto defaulter in jsp ");
                    %>
                    <tr>
                       <td>
                                <button href="#edit-modal" type="button" data-toggle="modal"
                                    class="btn btn-default" data-target="#editModal" data-loginidedit = "<%=loginIdEdit %>">Edit</button> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <%
                            }
                        %>
                </table>



//Modal here
                        <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">                                     
                                    </div>
                                 <form class="contact"> //give action, method attribute here or make ajax call on save button clicked,

                          <input type="hidden" name="????" id="loginid">// the modal on shown will fill this value.

                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="sel1"><span></span>Select status:</label> <select
                                            class="form-control" id="sel1" name="sel1">
                                            <option>Validate Error</option>
                                            <option>Auto Weaver</option>
                                            <option>ReDefault</option>
                                        </select>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="defaultercomment"><span></span>Add
                                            comment:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                            name="defaultercomment" id="defaultercomment"<%-- value="<%=loginIdEdit%>" --%>>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" id="save" name="save"
                                            class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" align="centre">Done</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

</body>
</html>



           $(function() {
                            //twitter bootstrap script
                            $("button#save").click(function(e) {

                                $.ajax({

                                    type : "POST",
                                    url : "defaulterUpdater.jsp",
                                    data : $('form.contact').serialize(),
                                    success : function(msg) {

                                    },
                                    error : function() {
                                        alert("Failed");
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
```

Comment: Anil can you please elaborate a little more?